# Tela não se ajusta

Tags: html, wordpress

Estou usando Wordpress. No computador, a página a seguir: http://jqnews.gq/quadro-de-horarios/ , mostra todas as tabelas da maneira correta.

Já no celular e aparelhos com telas menores, as tabelas ficam incompletas. Pela metade, ou coisa parecida.

IMAGENS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas esta tabela é o que **html**?

Comment: Fica "cortando" simplesmente pq a tabela não cabe na tela por ser grande de mais. Além disso em algum lugar do seu código deve ter um overflow:hidden, que não deixa rolar a página na horizontal para ver a tabela toda

Comment: Ja tive problemas nesse sentido e a solução é colocar um overflow na horizontal. Nao tem como voce exibir uma tabela deste tamanho em uma tela menor. ou voce criar com div quando o dispositivo estiver em um determinado tamanho

Answer (score 0):

Sua div id="primary" ta float right isso joga todos os elementos dela para direita.
Usa div com width mas com % ex 70% e os elementos maiores, tipo o horário do primeiro ano, você coloca em outra div, vai separando assim.

Comment: Como eu faço isso no wordpress?

Comment: Você criou esse tema ou você está usando algo pronto do wordpress?

Comment: Estou usando um tema

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo te ajudar nesse caso, você precisaria entrar na parte de programação do código para poder fazer essas alterações.